# Unable to execute a step on a running EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster 5.28.1 running in AWS but I forgot to install from python libraries as part of the bootstrap action. Now that the cluster is running, I was simply attempting to add a step via the EMR console. Here are my settings

```
JAR: s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar
Main class: None
Arguments: s3://xxxx/install_python_libraries.sh
```

Unfortunately, I get  the following error.

```
Cannot run program "s3://xxxxx/install_python_libraries.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The shell script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

# Non-standard and non-Amazon Machine Image Python modules:
sudo pip-3.6 install boto3
sudo pip-3.6 install xmltodict
```

I also tried this by simply using 'command-runner.jar' but I get the same error. Can you please help me figure out the problem so I do this via the console? I would like to install the libraries on all nodes - master and core.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a permission issue. Are you sure that the role used for EMR has proper s3 permissions to access the script?

Comment: @bdcloud. I think you might have a point. Never thought that error would mean permission issue. Will try it out.

Comment: Can you confirm if IAM policy was the issue?

Comment: Fixed the role and I think I got past that message. Now, I am getting java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-36C0OJUGLXXXX/./install_python_libraries.sh" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory. When I go to that directory the  shell file has been transferred successfully but notice the period (.) in the path above I am still adding the step as shown in my original question above. So, not sure how to solve this. And the shell file does have automatic execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the xxx.sh files EOL/carriage return type.

In other words, if it is Windows ("\r\n") then it will not work and return the ./ file not found error.

Convert it to unix type ("\n") using something like notepad++ and it will run fine.

(In notepad++ edit>EOL Conversion>Unix(LF) hit save and try again)